# Html2canvas library not picking up image only taking text and background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js, html2canvas

i am trying to take screen shoot of my div. In my div i have  a child component i am passing image in props to the child component. The images are being displayed perfectly. when i click on the component the html2canvas takes image of only text that is inside the component html2canvas function runs. It takes text and background in the child but not picking up the images on the div.

```
    Here is the source code of what i have tried to do:
    https://github.com/sidratariq/Signatureimage
```

Child component:
  ===================================

```
<div class="card" :style="{backgroundImage:'url('+thumbnail+')', position:'relative', }">
        <slot></slot>
        adjakdaja
</div>



 props: ["title", "previewtext", "thumbnail", "topspace", "bottomspace"],

    ==================================
    **Parent component**
    ----------------------------------
<Tomato
      ref="Tomato"
      @click.native="print('Tomato')"
      value="i am from the parent"
      thumbnail="http://theurbanrecipes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/shrimp-with-broccoli.jpg"
      title="Sidra"
      previewtext="awesome pizza"
      topspace="20"
      bottomspace="80"
    >
      <!-- loop for looping on  -->
      <div v-for="(i,index) in coordinates" :key="index">
        <img
          :style="{content:'url('+space+')',position:'absolute',top:i.Topcord+'px',left:i.Leftcord+'px',width:widthset,height:heightset}"
        >
      </div>
    </Tomato>

    <hr>
    <img :src="output">

data()=>{
coordinates: [
      {
        ContractID: "5c1c5ccf-529c-42da-b96e-65fbee2de18e",
        UserID: "",
        Name: "Signature",
        Topcord: 20,
        Leftcord: 210
      },
      {
        ContractID: "5c1c5ccf-529c-42da-b96e-65fbee2de18e",
        UserID: "",
        Name: "Initial",
        Topcord: 20,
        Leftcord: 426
      },
      {
        ContractID: "5c1c5ccf-529c-42da-b96e-65fbee2de18e",
        UserID: "",
        Name: "Name",
        Topcord: 0,
        Leftcord: 316
      }
    ],
    output:''
}
```

---

Comment: Please include a MINIMAL working version of your source code here directly in your post for other people to see in the future if your link goes away.

Comment: @ToddChaffee i have added minimal code but i am also going to keep the repo public.